# How to use two for loops to copy a list variable into a location variable in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has 2 columns called locStuff and data. Someone was kind enough to show me how to index a location range in the df so that it correctly changes the data to a single integer attached to locStuff instead of the dataframe index, that works fine, now I cannot see how to change the data values of that location range with a list of values.

```
import pandas as pd


INDEX = list(range(1, 11))
LOCATIONS = [3, 10, 6, 2, 9, 1, 7, 5, 8, 4]
DATA = [94, 43, 85, 10, 81, 57, 88, 11, 35, 86]
# Make dataframe
DF = pd.DataFrame(LOCATIONS, columns=['locStuff'], index=INDEX)
DF['data'] = pd.Series(DATA, index=INDEX)

# Location and new value inputs
LOC_TO_CHANGE = 8
NEW_LOC_VALUE = 999
NEW_LOC_VALUE = [999,666,333]


LOC_RANGE = list(range(3, 6))

DF.iloc[3:6, 1] = ('%03d' % NEW_LOC_VALUE)
print(DF)

#I TRIED BOTH OF THESE SEPARATELY
for i in NEW_LOC_VALUE:
    for j in LOC_RANGE:
        DF.iloc[j, 1] = ('%03d' % NEW_LOC_VALUE[i])


print (DF)

i=0
while i<len(NEW_LOC_VALUE):
    for j in LOC_RANGE:
        DF.iloc[j, 1] = ('%03d' % NEW_LOC_VALUE[i])
    i=+1

print(DF)
```

Neither of these work:

```
for i in NEW_LOC_VALUE:
    for j in LOC_RANGE:
        DF.iloc[j, 1] = ('%03d' % NEW_LOC_VALUE[i])


print (DF)

i=0
while i<len(NEW_LOC_VALUE):
    for j in LOC_RANGE:
        DF.iloc[j, 1] = ('%03d' % NEW_LOC_VALUE[i])
    i=+1
```

I know how to do this using loops or list comprehensions for an empty list but no idea how to adapt what I have above for a DataFrame.

Expected behaviour would be:

```
    locStuff data
1          3   999
2         10   43
3          6   85
4          2   10
5          9   81
6          1   57
7          7   88
8          5   333
9          8   35
10         4   666
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `locStuff` as index, assign values, and `reset_index`:

```
DF.set_index('locStuff', inplace=True)
DF.loc[LOC_RANGE, 'data'] = NEW_LOC_VALUE
DF.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
    locStuff    data
0   3           999
1   10          43
2   6           85
3   2           10
4   9           81
5   1           57
6   7           88
7   5           333
8   8           35
9   4           666
```

Comment: Hi Quang,when I run this:

Comment: Hi Quang, I see that it works but I don't understand why, is is that when you set the locStuff as the index and use loc instead of iloc it is then changing only those values in the LOC_RANGE? I'm not sure now why I chose bloc instead of loc in the first place.

Comment: @Windy71 in a nut shell, Yes.

Comment: Thanks Quang, much appreciated!